# Introduce local changes in git to specific comment in the past

Tags: git, git-rebase

Suppose I have 2 commits on top my master branch and some uncommited local changes.
`master -> commit 1 -> commit 2 -> (uncommited changes)`
In `commit 1` I changed just file A, in `commit 2` I changed just file B. Uncomitted changes contain both file A and B modifications.
I want to take all uncommited changes to file A and edit `commit 1` to contain these changes. Same with `commit 2` and file B. I have not pushed yet.
I tried to use `git rebase -i` with `git stash` but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$ git add -p
```

[interactively add your A changes]

```
$ git commit -m A
$ git add -p
```

[interactively add your B changes]

```
$ git commit -m B
```

Now you have four commits, each changing one file at a time. Now do

```
$ git rebase -i master
```

And reorder your commits to be commit 1, A, commit 2, B and mark A and B as fixup. Save and quit and it should rebase cleanly giving what you want.

Comment: Thanks Ben, one of my colleagues helped me with it using stash and rebase. After we succesfullly did it he proposed exact same solution as you did, which is much more elegant